# Order of galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

$\omega$ is a primitive 150th root of unity what is the order of $Gal\left(\mathbb{Q}\left(\omega\right)/\mathbb{Q}\right).$

There is result in Book that $Gal\left(\mathbb{Q}\left(\omega\right)/\mathbb{Q}\right)$ (where is $\omega$ is a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity) is isomorphic to $U(n).
$

so does both have same order

For 150th root we need to calculate order of $U(150)$ which is 40.

Therefore order of galois group is 40!!

But i need to calculate number of element of order 15 in galois group (That is the question in my assignment but i stuck at order of group so i just ask about order of group) which is not possible because 15 does not divide 40.

Did i calculate the order wrong? Is 40 correct order of that galois group?

Another way $x^{150}-1=(x^{75}-1)(x^{75}+1)$ where $x^{75}+1$ is irreducible so order of that group is 75!! Is it right?

I don't know what is right.

Any help!

Thanks.

Comment: $X^{75}+1=(X^{25}+1)(X^{50}-X^{25}+1)$ is reducible. The Galois group is as you initially said the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_{150}$.

Comment: 40 is the correct order of the group, and you have already deduced the number of elements of order 15. What is the remaining question?